# Why is the Suggested Meetings pane empty?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, office365

My office recently migrated to Outlook 2013 and Office 365. As part of the migration, employees were given access to a [Suggested Meetings](https://kb.wisc.edu/office365/page.php?id=55738) option to automatically suggest meeting times.

While this feature usually works as intended, occasionally the Suggested Meetings tab will fail to load, displaying only a blank white pane. This only happens on certain specific messages.

I haven't been able to notice any pattern as to why the suggested meetings tab works for some messages but fails on others. Outlook doesn't display any error messages or warnings when this happens.

**Why is the Suggested Meetings pane empty when viewing certain messages?**

[image: Empty Suggested Meetings pane]

Answer (score 0):

It could be for a variety of reasons.

Based on your descriptions, the add-in is working, so It could just be that the messages themselves did not trigger the rules and there is nothing to suggest for you.  It also could be some sort of API error that is just not surfacing the trace to you (probably something in the message that locks it up potentially).

Because of the way add-ins work - there is likely not anything you will be able to do to change this behavior.  You could get potentially get more details by installing and using Fiddler to look at the HTTP traces and see what the differences are between the add-in and it's service.  It looks like if you right click the add-in you can also attach a visual studio debugger to the instance (have zero experience with that - I just noticed it).